# Finding a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree 5 such that $f(x)$ is divisible by $x^3$ and $f(x)+2$ is divisible by $(x+1)^3.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

There is some polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $5$ such that both of these properties hold:

$f(x)$ is divisible by $x^3$.

$f(x)+2$ is divisible by $(x+1)^3.$

Find that polynomial.

I know that because $f(x)$ is divisible by $x^3$ our polynomial is in the form of $ax^5+bx^4+cx^3.$ However, I'm not very sure how our second condition comes into use. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)+2=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+2=(x^3+3x^2+3x+1)(dx^2+ex+f)$,

then multiplying out and equating coefficients yields

$a=d, b=e+3d, c=f+3e+3d, 0=d+3e+3f, 0=e+3f,$ and $ 2=f$.

This system is easy to solve for $a, b, c, d, e, $ and $f, $

and then the answer is $f(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3$.

Comment: Oh wait! This is the type of approach I'm looking for, solving we have $f(x)=12x^5+30x^4+20x^3?$

Comment: Yes, that is correct, @FrostBite

Comment: Wait, I'm not verysure about the first line. Like how did we get that $ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+2$ was equal to that stuff on the right?

Comment: because $f(x)$ is of degree $5$ and $f(x)+2$ is divisible by $(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$

Comment: Ohh, I see! This all makes sense now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

A degree $5$ polynomial divisible by $(x+1)^3$ is of the form
$$(x+1)^3(ax^2+bx+c)$$
Expand, subtract $2$, and see when this is a multiple of $x^3$.

Comment: This way requires the fewer calculations if I have to compare the 3 methods proposed so far (especially if we ignore terms in $x^3,x^4,x^5$).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- If $x-a\mid p(x)$ then $p(a)=0$
- If $(x-a)^2\mid p(x)$ then $p'(a)=0$
- If $(x-a)^3\mid p(x)$ then $p''(a)=0$

Comment: and it is even more useful when you specify that they are necessary and sufficient

Comment: This is tagged algebra, not calculus.

Comment: How would we start to apply this onto the problem, I'm not really sure.

I'm looking for an algebraic approach, without needing to use any calculus involved.

Comment: Put $p(x)=f(x)+2=ax^5+...+2$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equality
$$(x - (x+1) )^5 = -1$$
and [expand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) getting
$$x^5 - 5 x^4 (x+1) +10 x^3 (x+1)^2- 10 x^2 (x+1)^3 +5 x (x+1)^4 - (x+1)^5 = -1$$
or
$$x^5 - 5 x^4 (x+1) + 10 x^3 (x+1)^2 = -1 + (x+1)^3 Q(x)$$
Therefore the  polynomial is
$$2 x^3( x^2 - 5 x(x+1) + 10 (x+1)^2)$$